# Property 'X' is missing in type 'DefaultRootState' - but the property is declared in Interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-redux

Here's my Interface which I'm using with `mapStateToProps`:

```
export interface IStore {
  cache?: any;
  dataManager?: IUR;
  userPrefs: IUP;
  IModal?: IfingerprintModal;
}

export interface IModal {
  cbCancel: IFModalFn | null;
  cbTryAgain?: IFModalFn | null;
  error: null | string;
  success: boolean;
  visible: boolean;
}
```

Here's the `mapStateToProps` fn expression:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: IStore) => ({
  store: {
    IModal: state.userPrefs.IModal,
  },
});
```

And here's the `connect` HOC:

```
export default connect<IStore,{}>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(IModal);
```

That's the error I'm seeing:
[image]

I can get rid of the problem by:

```
export default connect<IStore>(mapStateToProps as any, mapDispatchToProps)(IModal);
```

But I am trying to find a generic solution to that

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the type from the `connect` call and let typescript to handle it for you:

`connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FingerprintModal);`

Otherwise you would need to specify the full type:

`connect<{store: IStore;}, {}, {}, IStore>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)`